# Передвижение кнопки вправо

Tags: android, android-button

У меня есть ImageButton. Мой ImageButton надо передвинуть вправо. Помните ли вы заблокированный экран Iphone 4, и чтобы его разблокировать, надо сдвинуть кнопку вправо? Так вот. С моим ImageButton нужно сделать тоже самое. Но при достижении определённых координат по оси x, ImageButton не может больше передвинуться вправо, но теперь может передвинуться влево. Надеюсь объяснил понятно.
Если возникнут какие-нибудь вопросы, пишите в комментарии.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю вполне можно обойтись кастомным `SwitchButton`, типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Исходники здесь](https://github.com/zcweng/SwitchButton)

Comment: Хорошо, а если это будет ImageButton? Как создать SwitchButton в Android Studio?

Comment: Кастомизировать можно, `SwitchButton` чтобы отображал некий `Image` - не думаю, что это сложно

Comment: Можете дополнить свой ответ, пожалуйста?